# NotePad++ Regular Expression Keep Some Characters The Same

Tags: regex

I am looking to keep certain characters the same when search/replacing a string - while deleting some characters. Specifically I want to search for all instances of this string:

*** BATCH *** [Qh 4c 2c] [9h] [9c]

and want to change it to this:

*** BATCH *** [Qh 4c 2c 9h] [9c]

My problem is that the characters inside the brackets change throughout the document. So I would also want to change this line:

*** BATCH *** [Js 8c 3s] [8h] [Th]

to this line

*** BATCH *** [Js 8c 3s 8h] [Th]

I can't simply search/delete ] [ as there are other instances of it that I need to keep. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Regex will make short work of this task :

Match `(\[\w{2} \w{2} \w{2})] \[(\w{2}])( \[\w{2}])`
Replace by `\1 \2\3`

[Regex101 sample](https://regex101.com/r/grGj2W/3).

The matched pattern represents as much as I know of your actual pattern in order to avoid replacement where it shouldn't and use `(capturing groups)` to extract the relevant informations, which are referenced in the replacement pattern to reproduce the data in another format.